# Is there a way to reverse each 2 bytes of a file?

Tags: c#

Basic summary of what I'm trying to achieve in this idea (As far as that I know there isn't exactly a function to do what I'm doing).

What I need to do is idea is to reverse every 2 bytes of a file. Reading a file bytes and reversing each 2 bytes.

```
Example: 05 04 82 FF
Output: 04 05 FF 82
```

I have some idea of it. But I know my attempts are WAY off.

To clarify.

1. I'm trying to take a bin file.
2. Read the bytes inside the file.
3. And reversing every 2 inside that file and close it.

If anyone can clear this complicated way up that would be great?

Comment: How did you try to do it specifically? "Reading a file bytes and reversing each 2 bytes" sounds reasonable by itself, but the details could go wrong

Comment: @harold At first I was using Array.Reverse(); to reverse the file bytes but that one actually reverses the ENTIRE file bytes. Which is of course not what i wanted. I was using a Binaryreader class to help with it. But it failed horribly lol. So i deleted it.

Comment: Read two single bytes. Write each one out in the opposite order from how they were read. Repeat until you've reached the end of the file. Or read the whole file, and then process it two bytes at a time, swapping them, and then write the entire file back out again. Or read a chunk of the file (e.g., 1 kB), and then go through two bytes at a time, swapping each pair of bytes, and then write the chunk out to a new file and repeat the process. You are aware that doing what you're doing may corrupt the file, right?

Comment: @KenWhite Im very aware. But yes you have the exact concept of what i need.

Comment: *If*, say, this were UTF-16 text and you wanted to change the endianness of the encoding, you'd be better off using the specific tools designed to work with encodings. But if this is arbitrary data then yes, just work at the byte level.

Comment: It *sounds* like you're probably dealing with UTF-16 endianness - is it a text file? Frankly, if so: there are both endian UTF-16 encodings available in .NET; perhaps just read it in one, and write it in the other? It won't be as performant as a byte-level streaming approach, but it'll be 5 lines of code instead of 50, and it'll probably be right first time (which has value)

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches you could take to achieve this.

Here is a fairly efficient *streaming* approach with low *allocations*, using all the *characters* we know and love.... `ArrayPool`, `Span<T>`, and `FileStream`.

<sub>***Note 1** : Adjust the buffer size to something that suits your hardware if needed.*</sub>

<sub>***Note 2** : This lacks basic sanity checks and fault tolerance, it will also die miserably if the size of the file isn't devisable by `2`.*</sub>

**Given**

```
private static ArrayPool<byte> pool = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared;
private const int BufferSize = 4096;

public static void Swap(string fileName)
{
   var tempFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, "bob");   
   var buffer = pool.Rent(BufferSize);

   try
   {
      var span = new Span<byte>(buffer); 
      using var oldFs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, BufferSize);
      using var newFs = new FileStream(tempFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, BufferSize);

      var size = 0;
      while ((size = oldFs.Read(span)) > 0)
      {
         for (var i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
         {
            var temp = span[i];
            span[i] = span[i + 1];
            span[i + 1] = temp;
         }   
         newFs.Write(span.Slice(0,size));
      }
   }
   finally
   {
      pool.Return(buffer);
   }

   File.Move(tempFileName, fileName,true);
}
```

**Test**

```
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Test1.txt","1234567890abcdef");
Swap(@"D:\Test1.txt");

var result = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Test1.txt");

Console.WriteLine(result == "2143658709badcfe");
```

**Output**

```
True
```

## Benchmarks

This was just a simple benchmark comparing the current solution with a simple array approach and pointers, varying the buffer size which you might do to increase HDD throughput. Technically it's only benchmarking one run through of a 10Mb data block, However the allocations would *sky rocket* if the methods got run more than once.

**Environment**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.18363.1198 (1909/November2018Update/19H2)
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, 1 CPU, 24 logical and 12 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.100
  [Host]        : .NET Core 5.0.0 (CoreCLR 5.0.20.51904, CoreFX 5.0.20.51904), X64 RyuJIT  [AttachedDebugger]
  .NET Core 5.0 : .NET Core 5.0.0 (CoreCLR 5.0.20.51904, CoreFX 5.0.20.51904), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET Core 5.0  Runtime=.NET Core 5.0
```

**Results**

```
|       Method |     N |        Mean |    Error |   StdDev |  Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------- |------ |------------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
| SwapSpanPool |  4094 |    25.89 ns | 0.078 ns | 0.069 ns |      - |     - |     - |         - |
|    SwapArray |  4094 |   157.70 ns | 0.516 ns | 0.483 ns | 0.4923 |     - |     - |    4120 B |
|   SwapUnsafe |  4094 |   154.71 ns | 0.293 ns | 0.274 ns | 0.4923 |     - |     - |    4120 B |
|------------- |------ |------------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
| SwapSpanPool | 16384 |    25.82 ns | 0.048 ns | 0.043 ns |      - |     - |     - |         - |
|    SwapArray | 16384 |   520.62 ns | 1.186 ns | 1.109 ns | 1.9569 |     - |     - |   16408 B |
|   SwapUnsafe | 16384 |   518.82 ns | 1.361 ns | 1.273 ns | 1.9569 |     - |     - |   16408 B |
|------------- |------ |------------:|---------:|---------:|-------:|------:|------:|----------:|
| SwapSpanPool | 65536 |    25.81 ns | 0.049 ns | 0.043 ns |      - |     - |     - |         - |
|    SwapArray | 65536 | 1,840.41 ns | 5.792 ns | 5.418 ns | 7.8106 |     - |     - |   65560 B |
|   SwapUnsafe | 65536 | 1,846.57 ns | 3.715 ns | 3.475 ns | 7.8106 |     - |     - |   65560 B |
```

**Setup**

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.NetCoreApp50)]
public class DumbTest
{
   private static readonly ArrayPool<byte> pool = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared;

   private MemoryStream ms1;
   private MemoryStream ms2;

   [Params(4094, 16384, 65536)] public int N;

   [GlobalSetup]
   public void Setup()
   {
      var data = new byte[10 * 1024 * 1024];
      new Random(42).NextBytes(data);
      ms1 = new MemoryStream(data);
      ms2 = new MemoryStream(new byte[10 * 1024 * 1024]);
   }

   public void SpanPool()
   {
      var buffer = pool.Rent(N);
      try
      {
         var span = new Span<byte>(buffer);

         var size = 0;
         while ((size = ms1.Read(span)) > 0)
         {
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
            {
               var temp = span[i];
               span[i] = span[i + 1];
               span[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            ms2.Write(span.Slice(0, size));
         }
      }
      finally
      {
         pool.Return(buffer);
      }
   }

   public void Array()
   {
      var buffer = new byte[N];
      var size = 0;
      while ((size = ms1.Read(buffer)) > 0)
      {
         for (var i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
         {
            var temp = buffer[i];
            buffer[i] = buffer[i + 1];
            buffer[i + 1] = temp;
         }

         ms2.Write(buffer, 0, size);
      }
   }

   public unsafe void Unsafe()
   {
      var buffer = new byte[N];

      fixed (byte* p = buffer)
      {
         var size = 0;
         while ((size = ms1.Read(buffer)) > 0)
         {
            for (var i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
            {
               var temp = buffer[i];
               p[i] = p[i + 1];
               p[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            ms2.Write(buffer, 0, size);
         }
      }
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void SwapSpanPool()
   {
      SpanPool();
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void SwapArray()
   {
      Array();
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public void SwapUnsafe()
   {
      Unsafe();
   }
}
```